# joi validation each items of array object must have same value

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi, hapi

i have form request like this

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "transaction": "LNS",
            "product": "XXX",
            "lot": "1",
            "liquidPrice": "0",
            "liquidId": 0,
            "limitPrice": "1780.00",
            "stopPrice": "0"
        },
        {
            "transaction": "LNS",
            "product": "XXX",
            "lot": "1",
            "liquidPrice": "0",
            "liquidId": 0,
            "limitPrice": "1780.00",
            "stopPrice": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

i want to check if the array data bigger than one object, the value of key object product must same as another array of object

Comment: Can you explain your requirement by an example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps for check of key object

1. Compare each and every element of two arrays.
2. Return the matched element.
3. Add the element or object into the object of array.

Check this example :

```js
let Joi = require('joi')
let service = Joi.object().keys({
  serviceName: Joi.string().required(),
})

let services = Joi.array().items(service)

let test = Joi.validate(
  [{ serviceName: 'service1' }, { serviceName: 'service2' }],
  services,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you using Joi validation libary:

```
Joi.array().items({
     "transaction": Joi.string().required(),
      ...
}).min(1)
```